# Why was Teletype Corporation's Model 33 ASR console always mounted on a metal stand?

Tags: terminal

Why are all complete Teletype Corporation Model 33 ASR shown mounted on a dedicated metal stand?

Comment: You’ve already answered the original question, which was already specifically about the ASR. There’s no need to duplicate the question.

Comment: Creating a question to repost the very same answer one has already given to the same question does sound like abuse, doesn't it?

Comment: This looks to me as a question that was simply duplicated to be able to post a "but I was right" answer. If that is a misunderstanding, please clarify.

Comment: Catch is the answer that has been previously upvoted and has been accepted is wrong. Somebody searching for an answer regarding the metal stand will be mistaken if they accept that upvoted answer and beleive the metal stand was only an optional part. The Model 33 ASR was never sold without the metal stand. Although I've attempted to have the answer corrected that has not occurred. The only way on StackExchange to correct such an an incorrect answer is to repost a question and provide a correct answer. StackExchange is not Wikipedia and this StackExchange process has been a design choice.

Comment: @PDP11 The stack exchange process is not intended to be used to force a single persons opinion but to satisfy the one asking - supported by popular voting. The outcome might have been in part due to your answer (and comments) repeating the absolute claim of _'The Model 33 ASR was never sold without the metal stand'_ without giving any substantial support. Improve that answer to prove it, or finally accept that your opinion is just that, an opinion from a limited viewpoint - but please abstain from trying to twist the system to force your personal view.

Comment: Updated my answer to the previous question with the new information just found and revised. Pretty pointless exercise as that is an old question with an incorrect, upvoted and accepted answer. Not expressing a personal opinion from a limited viewpoint, just dumped the relevant Teletype documentation decades ago about the same time as my UNIVAC I engineering drawings.

Comment: I believe the questioner can unaccept my answer and accept yours, if he is convinced by the new argumentation (and he's still paying attention to the question of course).

Comment: We could also choose to unpin accepted answers, which would allow newer unaccepted answers to be given the top spot if they get the most votes; see [this meta discussion](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1144/79).

Comment: No change to correct the accepted answer to the previous question. Edited the question to better reflect the issues with the Model 33 ASR.

Comment: Finally found the Teletype Corporation's Product Description for the Model 33 ASR. This confirms the stand was mandatory and not an optional extra. Will update both answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Teletype Model 33 ASR variant used as a retro-computer terminal was sold with a metal stand. The reference is [Teletype Corporation, 1969 Price List and Product Descriptions M28, M32, M33, M35](https://www.navy-radio.com/manuals/tty/tty-equip-price-1969-02.pdf):

```
Teletype Corporation
Product Descriptionn 50 (P.D. 50)
Change 11
Dated October 1, 1969
    
Teletype Corporation Model 33Cl Standard Duty Send-Receive Page
Printer Set with Tape Perforator and Reader with these features: 
        
Equipment Features and Components
        
Tape Reader Features
Power pack mounted in sheet metal stand
        
General Information
Set shipped completely assembled less stand and chad box
    
Dimensions
Stand: (Supports teletypewriter)
```

The stand was integral to the Model 33 ASR while it was optional for the RO and KSR variant.

The Teletype Model 33 variants used an eight level code and were typically seen in computer installations. The Bitsavers site currently has [Technical Bulletin 273B](https://www.google.com/search?q=ASR33%20advertisement&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiEo6Xe0_KDAxXIlWMGHSytCNkQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ASR33%20advertisement&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CWJFjsKWCJU2gAcAB4AIABnwGIAboEkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=_z2vZcSnNMirjuMPrNqiyA0&bih=735&biw=2048&rlz=1C1SQJL_enAU880AU880&hl=en#imgrc=mNJi8S5JtzViXM) , a copy of the Teletype Corporation:

```
Technical Bulletin 273B
Technical Manual
Manual Model 32 and 33
Send-Receive Page Printer Sets (KSR)
Receive-Only Page Printer Sets (RO)
Automatic Send and Receive Sets (ASR)
```

Other relevant Teletype manuals covered spare parts, wiring diagrams, etc. A three volume maintenance documentation set was available.

A standard Teletype Model 33 ASR console was always sold **installed on a metal stand** and not on a flat desk. That is why they were typically seen in computer installations with the metal stand.

In the Teletype Corporation manual being used as the source material some variants of a Model 33 teletype could easily be used without the metal stand. Catch is the Teletype Model 33 ASR is the exception due to the papertape reader and punch.

A page printer only mechanism i.e. the Model 33 RO model (Receive Only) could have easily been installed on a flat desktop or table as it didn't have the papertape reader or punch. The keyboard Send-Receive (KSR) model did not have a papertape reader or punch so a desk could be a viable option.

It is very likely that people sitting at a teletype on a desk would not know the difference between the a Model 33 KSR they were using and the Model 33 ASR model.

The Model 33 ASR with the papertape punch requires a box to catch the chads. This was below the level of the subtray and required the metal stand. For sites that needed papertape punch functionality of the Model 33 ASR they needed the metal stand. The component list of the ASR 33 always included the papertape punch while the other variants didn't include the punch.

The Teletype manual described the RO and KSR variants that could be easily installed on a flat table. Therefore the metal stand is described as an optional extra. The reference is:

```
Section 1 Description
1-9. STAND (Figure 1-2).
Available as an accessory is a sheet metal
stand which will support the equipment at 
a convenient operating level. ...
```

At this point an assumption could be made that the metal stand was optional for all variants. The text continues:

```
It consists of chrome feet and an enclosure
which will house auxilary apparatus such 
as a Data Set and reader power pack. A 
removable rear panel provides access to this
enclosure. ...
```

The Teletype Model 33 ASR included a papertape reader and punch that required the eclosure on the metal stand.

For the Model 33 ASR the manual includes Section 2 Installation,

```
2-16 Power Pack Assembly, b.
The Auxiliary ASR Power Supply is 
mounted in the enclosure of the stand.

2-17 Tape Punch, b.
Installation of Chad Box Assembly (Figure 2-13),
(2) Push the box towards the rear until
a bent surface located at the front of 
the box engages the printer stand.
```

Additionally the manual includes:

```
Section 7 Principles of Operation
7-17 Tape Reader
The power pack is attached inside the
printer stand.
```

As the teletype use mains power (e.g. 110Vac) operator safety dictates that the papertape reader power pack had to be installed in an enclosure. This enclosure was incorporated into the metal stand. The metal stand was also required to mount the chad box for the tape punch. Note the metal stand is in the referenced figure for the punch in the manual.

Therefore the Teletype Model 33 ASR required the stand which was optional for the Model 33 series RO and KSR variants which were also included in the Model 33 series manual.

Edit:-
An advertisement by Teletype Corporation for the [Model 33ASR](https://www.google.com/search?q=ASR33%20advertisement&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiEo6Xe0_KDAxXIlWMGHSytCNkQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ASR33%20advertisement&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CWJFjsKWCJU2gAcAB4AIABnwGIAboEkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=_z2vZcSnNMirjuMPrNqiyA0&bih=735&biw=2048&rlz=1C1SQJL_enAU880AU880&hl=en#imgrc=mNJi8S5JtzViXM) displayed the base model plus options. The Base Model for $840 included the metal stand, manual reader etc.

Comment: using google to find pictures of "Teletype Model 33 ASR", there are a lot found with, but also many without stand. Maybe it was often sold with stand, but for sure no always, or people removed it from the stand afterwards. But obviously it would work without the stand. 
just because it was often sold with that option, it doesn't make that option mandatory

Comment: The original manufacturer's advertisement provided as a reference listed the options that could be purchased. The metal stand was not an option. The metal stand was included in the purchase price.

Comment: Next reference from the 1973 is the picture on page 50 of an ASR33. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/the-use-of-the-dedicated-metal-stand-with-the-teletype-model-33-asr-console/28333?noredirect=1#comment102365_28333

Comment: I could bolt a teletype by its metal stand to the ceiling. That doesn't mean that operating upside down using a broom handle should  be accepted as an operating mode. Found another original advertisment for the 33ASR and again it shows for 14 years the Model 33 ASR was always sold with a metal stand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Teletype_Model_33_Terminal_June_1974.jpg

Comment: Another original source with a Model 33 ASR on it's metal stand. https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/110698972?searchTerm=Teletype%20model%2033

Comment: Even the mobile version of a Model 33 ASR included a metal stand. Must admit I'd never seen one of these. https://www.pdp8online.com/asr33/pics/old_sound.shtml?small

Comment: Finally found a picture that includes the three volume maintenance set that I used to have for my Model 33 ASR. https://www.pdp8online.com/asr33/pics/front.shtml?small I've been unable to find any original Teletype Corporation source for the Model 33 ASR without a metal stand.

Comment: Found the Teletype Corporation's 1969 Product Description and price list for the Model 33 ASR. Incorporated into the answer.